# Get row clicked in a table - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following HTML Code. This is a table that fetches a list of items from costList and displays them in different rows. I want the item value to be displayed on the row click. How do I implement it in Angular. Thank You in advance.

```
    <table>
        <tr ng-click = "displayItem()" ng-repeat = "item in costList">
            <td>{{item}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: You can pass the item as a parameter in your displayItem() function like this displayItem(item) and use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ng-click="displayItem(item)"
```

or you can store the item in displayItem.

```
$scope.displayItem = function (item) { $scope.currentItem = item; }

<div>{{currentItem}}</div>
```

Comment: that was Easy ! Thanks Man

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "I want the item value to be displayed on the row click". If you just want it to appear when the row is clicked, try this:

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr  ng-repeat = "item in costList">
    <td ng-click="display = !display">
      <span ng-show="display">{{item}}</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/BSjv4Bv7Ouf4Y49cAtgx?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```
 <table>
        <tr ng-click = "selectedItem = item" ng-repeat = "item in costList">
            <td>{{selectedItem}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.